# Build a list with a while loop using DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say we're Amazon, and we receive a customer order in the form of this nested dict down here

```
order = {"order_id": 123, "requested": [{"product_id": 0, "quantity": 2}, {"product_id": 10, "quantity": 4}]}
```

Problem: Our boxes have a weight limit. Each box can only fit 1800g of product. Easy enough; I wrote code to perform that check. Where I'm stuck is this little tidbit: **If the order can't fit in one box, we're supposed to split the order into multiple boxes until the whole order is shipped.** 
To find weight and other info about each product, we reference this list of dicts:

```
product_info = [{"mass_g": 700, "product_name": "RBC A+ Adult", "product_id": 0}, {"mass_g": 700, "product_name": "RBC B+ Adult", "product_id": 1}, {"mass_g": 750, "product_name": "RBC AB+ Adult", "product_id": 2}, {"mass_g": 680, "product_name": "RBC O- Adult", "product_id": 3}, {"mass_g": 350, "product_name": "RBC A+ Child", "product_id": 4}, {"mass_g": 200, "product_name": "RBC AB+ Child", "product_id": 5}, {"mass_g": 120, "product_name": "PLT AB+", "product_id": 6}, {"mass_g": 80, "product_name": "PLT O+", "product_id": 7}, {"mass_g": 40, "product_name": "CRYO A+", "product_id": 8}, {"mass_g": 80, "product_name": "CRYO AB+", "product_id": 9}, {"mass_g": 300, "product_name": "FFP A+", "product_id": 10}, {"mass_g": 300, "product_name": "FFP B+", "product_id": 11}, {"mass_g": 300, "product_name": "FFP AB+", "product_id": 12}]
```

I compare the lists using DataFrame from the Pandas module. Here's my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd

def split_shipment(order, product_info):
    product_info_df = pd.DataFrame(product_info).set_index("product_id")
    order_df = pd.DataFrame(order["requested"]).set_index("product_id")
    order_weight = order_df.join(product_info_df)[['quantity', 'mass_g']].prod(1).sum()
    product_weights = order_df.join(product_info_df)[['quantity', 'mass_g']].to_numpy()
    shipment = [] #output will be a list of dicts containing order_id and quantities
    #for i in order:
        #shipment.append(product)
        #???
    print(shipment)
```

If we feed this code the order list at the top, expected output would be:

```
{"shipment_id": 0, "shipped": [{"product_id": 0, "quantity": 2}, {"product_id":10, "quantity":1}]}
{"shipment_id": 1, "shipped": [{"product_id":10, "quantity":3}]}
```

Please help, I am so stuck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you use pandas - you can do this using simple python with no imports whatsoever:

```
# ok, 1 import - but that is just for printing convenience ;)
from pprint import pprint

od = {"order_id": 123, "requested": [{"product_id": 0, "quantity": 2}, 
                                     {"product_id": 10, "quantity": 4}]} 

# badly structured - we reformat it into a lookup dict based on product_id
pi = [{"mass_g": 700, "product_name": "RBC A+ Adult", "product_id": 0}, 
    {"mass_g": 700, "product_name": "RBC B+ Adult", "product_id": 1}, 
    {"mass_g": 750, "product_name": "RBC AB+ Adult", "product_id": 2}, 
    {"mass_g": 680, "product_name": "RBC O- Adult", "product_id": 3}, 
    {"mass_g": 350, "product_name": "RBC A+ Child", "product_id": 4}, 
    {"mass_g": 200, "product_name": "RBC AB+ Child", "product_id": 5}, 
    {"mass_g": 120, "product_name": "PLT AB+", "product_id": 6}, 
    {"mass_g": 80, "product_name": "PLT O+", "product_id": 7}, 
    {"mass_g": 40, "product_name": "CRYO A+", "product_id": 8}, 
    {"mass_g": 80, "product_name": "CRYO AB+", "product_id": 9}, 
    {"mass_g": 300, "product_name": "FFP A+", "product_id": 10}, 
    {"mass_g": 300, "product_name": "FFP B+", "product_id": 11}, 
    {"mass_g": 300, "product_name": "FFP AB+", "product_id": 12}]

# better usable lookup
bpi = {dic["product_id"]:dic for dic in pi }

# get a list of all products for scheduling for packing
products = [ bpi[k] for b in ([inner["product_id"]]*inner["quantity"] 
                               for inner in od["requested"]) for k in b]

pprint(products)
print()

# packaging
max_w = 1800
# we start with one empty package and remember how much room is left
remaining = { 0 : max_w}
packages = [[]]

# now we schedule stuff, if needed we create a new empty package with appropriate room
# if one item does not fit any already prepared packages
for p in products:
    mass = p["mass_g"]
    done = False
    # look if it fits anywhere
    for i in remaining:
        if remaining[i] >= mass:
            packages[i].append(p)
            remaining[i] -= mass
            done = True
            break
    # does not fit, use new package
    if not done:
        remaining[i+1] = max_w - mass
        packages.append([p])

pprint(packages)
```

Output:

```
# order items
[{'mass_g': 700, 'product_id': 0, 'product_name': 'RBC A+ Adult'},
 {'mass_g': 700, 'product_id': 0, 'product_name': 'RBC A+ Adult'},
 {'mass_g': 300, 'product_id': 10, 'product_name': 'FFP A+'},
 {'mass_g': 300, 'product_id': 10, 'product_name': 'FFP A+'},
 {'mass_g': 300, 'product_id': 10, 'product_name': 'FFP A+'},
 {'mass_g': 300, 'product_id': 10, 'product_name': 'FFP A+'}]

# packaging
[[{'mass_g': 700, 'product_id': 0, 'product_name': 'RBC A+ Adult'},
  {'mass_g': 700, 'product_id': 0, 'product_name': 'RBC A+ Adult'},
  {'mass_g': 300, 'product_id': 10, 'product_name': 'FFP A+'}],
 [{'mass_g': 300, 'product_id': 10, 'product_name': 'FFP A+'},
  {'mass_g': 300, 'product_id': 10, 'product_name': 'FFP A+'},
  {'mass_g': 300, 'product_id': 10, 'product_name': 'FFP A+'}]]
```

You can regroup your data if you want a shorter output.

Comment: Thank you SO much!!! This has had me stumped for a long, long time! You saved me.